# Where are Event/Callbacks stored in the DOM tree?

Tags: html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I am building a one-page web application. I have to construct nested Backbone.View dynamically.

Usually I construct an empty jQuery, add divs into it, finish event binding on it, then return
that jQuery object.

I notice that the event bound on that object is retained if I append the jQuery object rather than append object.html().

I am confused that where are this events/callbacks in that jQuery object stored and how are this callbacks carried to the DOM tree when I insert a jQuery object.

Further, I would like to know in which condition I have to re-bind the callbacks after DOM manipulating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Backbone events object is basically short hand for doing event binding. Can you not make use of it? It is a much more standard approach. Your approach is non-standard and is likely going to cause confusion. If you need to stay dynamic, you could attach the events using the [convention explained on the Backbone website](http://backbonejs.org/#Events).

You will need to rebind the events if you remove the DOM or add it back. Depending on how the view works, you may need to rebind the events if a model change triggers a view refresh. The Backbone events hash takes care of that though.

jQuery did indeed keep the events attached to a DOM node in `.data('events')` however that is [going away with 1.8](https://github.com/IanLunn/Sequence/issues/118) (you can still get to it but it is not supposed to be used for purposes other than debugging). You can't inspect the DOM for events normally. This makes debugging very hard. If you use jQuery to attach events, it makes debugging easier as you can use the un-minified jQuery and put a break on where it dispatches the events. Chrome is also good for debugging event issues. But ideally you want to prevent them before you have them. I am hoping more tools will come out (like say an events plugin to PhantomJS that lets you monitor and debug events under test).

Answer (score 0):

As an implementation detail, events bound to `$('some-selector')` are stored in
`$('some-selector').data('events')`.

Not that you, as a jQuery user, need to ever worry about that.